# Finding a coordinate vector for specific basis

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I am having trouble with a specific problem concerning coordinate vectors. I have a basis $B' = \{t^2 + 2, t + 3, t^2 + t + 1\} $and a polynomial $p(t) = 4t^2 - t$. so I believed the way to go about finding a coordinate vector with respect to a specific basis was to do the following:
$[4t^2 -t]_{B'} = a(t^2 + 2) + b(t + 3) + c(t^2 + t + 1)$ 
Now I tried solving this by throwing it into the matrix
$$
\left(\!\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\!\!\right)
$$
so i got a wild solution consisting of fractions and it didn't add up. I got
$$
\frac{1}{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
10 \\
-13 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(I tried RREF) so I'm left a little confused how to approach this problem and any help would be appreciated. I've never had to deal with a more complex basis then the regular standard basis. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it needs a matrix version. According to what you noted, you need to solve $$(4t^2-t)=a(t^2+2)+b(t+3)+c(t^2+t+1)$$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$. So we have $$(a+c)t^2=4t^2\\(b+c)t=-t\\(2a+3b+c)=0$$ or $$(a+c)=4\\(b+c)=-1\\(2a+3b+c)=0$$

Comment: wow - thanks that will help me a lot

Comment: @user1787262: Welcome!

Comment: nice answer! +1

Comment: I'm not having a good (evening for me)$ (wee hours of the morning for you!). I guess it's partly because it's somewhat slow tonight. I should probably think about getting to sleep at a decent hour!

Comment: @amWhy: I inly wish you have a nice deep sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The equations obtained in Babak S.'s answer shows that you had the wrong matrix. The equation is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
For some reason you got the transpose of the actual matrix. So you need to do RREF on the following matrix
$$
\left(\!\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\!\!\right)
$$
and you should get the right answer.